# Select religion & want its caste to be displayed?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am making a matrimonial portal in php. I want to select religion & want its caste to be displayed. Religion & caste is dynamic and is coming from database. Please help me out.I tried in Many sites. But i cant get it..

Comment: post your code what have you tried?

Comment: i have no idea about that. I can find only religion in other sites. I cant get Castes correctly. If u have any samples send me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make 2 table for religion and caste where you can insert religion_Id and religion_Name in religion table and in other caste table make 3 columns caste_Id,religion_Id(foreign key from religion table), and caste_Name and based on religion tables id you can fetch all the caste from second table like below

```
select * from caste where religion_Id='your_religion_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Associative array in PHP.
Store the Religion value and as key, and the caste value as value.

Syntax

```
$religion = array('Hindu'=>'Caste_X', 'Islam'=>'Caste_Y', 'Christianity'=>'Caste_Z');
```